# How to change the way ClickOnce is deployed

Tags: clickonce

I've published a WPF app for ClickOnce deployment, to a network share. Now I've been told it needs to be changed to an Intranet web deployment. (Wish I'd known that before...)

So how do I change how a ClickOnce deployment is deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful post by Johann Blais @ http://johannblais.blogspot.com/2009/04/change-deployment-url-of-clickonce.html shows you how to move an existing app without forcing users to uninstall and reinstall, as long as your app that is already deployed is configured to check for updates. In summary, you deploy out a version in your new location that only knows how to update itself from the new location, then you deploy out a version in the old location that only knows how to update itself from the new location. When the publish version numbers are configured as below, your app will go to the correct location for updates.

1. In VS, adjust your project so:

   1. Publish Folder:  new file path (to a folder you can write to on your webserver, e.g. \mywebserver\uploads\myapp
   2. Installation folder (blank, takes above)
   3. Updates folder (blank, takes above)
   4. Publish Version: a couple of versions above what your current version is.
2. Publish your project.
3. In VS adjust your project so:

   1. Publish Folder: old deployment path, e.g. your existing fileshare
   2. Installation folder: (blank, takes above)
   3. Updates folder: URL from your webserver http://mywebserver/myclickonceapp/
   4. Version: has to be greater than what
      is installed on the clients smaller than the new
      deployment in step 1.4)
4. Publish Project

As long as your clients are configured to auto-update, you can move from file share to file share, file share to web (and probably visa versa) using Johann's steps above.

Comment: Thank you G, for your response. I see now that I wasn't clear enough yesterday when I posted my question. At this point no one has installed the app, so I've got a chance to change things. Looking over what you've written I do have a problem, though. We've got a build server and it can write to a location on its local storage, which is shared out to users. I don't have write privileges to that, though. So I don't know how I can get into VS and publish to the new location on the build server when I don't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Scratch what I just said. I was told I didn't have access to that server's network share - I do. I've changed where it's will publish so that it now publishes to that network share's location. Thank you, G!